# Google Agent Assist - Simulator view - feature FAQ, article suggestion CHECKBOX disabled

Tags: google-assistant

While working on simulator of Google Agent assist, the checkbox to enable FAQ or Article Suggestion or smart reply option is DISABLED.

The chat on simulator is working with virtual agent I have configured via Dialog flow with intents that I have built, but can't use agent assist feature since I am not able to enable it.

Please note I have configured smart reply, article suggestion and Knowledge Base option in the agent assist in my google project.

Looking for help to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening because, I was using a virtual agent. The moment I disabled the virtual agent (created via dialogflow), I was able to see all the options in the simulator